# passing more than one argument to connection_handler in c? I want to pass one more integer argument to connection_handler

Tags: c

Below code is for connection handler. Right now it has only one argument. How do I pass more than one argument to it

```
 while(client_sock=accept(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr*)&client,
    (socklen_t*)&c))
       {
           puts("Connection accepted");

           pthread_t sniffer_thread;
           new_sock = malloc(1);
           *new_sock = client_sock;

           if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler ,
(void*) new_sock) < 0)
            {
            perror("could not create thread");
           `enter code here`return 1;
        }

        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    x++;
    //code for connection handler
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a struct type for all the arguments you want.

malloc an instance of it.

Load it up with data.

Pass the addres of it into pthread_create().

free() it when the connection_handler exits.